# SQL Server: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter' threw an exception

Tags: sql, oracle, client, data-access, xp-cmdshell

After googling out a lot this seems a unique situation hope I find answer to it.

**Problem:**
I am trying to execute a .net console application from SQL server using XP_CMDSHELL

For e.g

**XP_CMDSHELL '\\sharedlocation\sharedfolder\dotnetconsoleapp.exe'**

I am able to execute this successfully when I execute this exe from regular command prompt but face below error when i use XP_CMDSHELL to execute this console application.

The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter' threw an exception.

**Way of Implementation**

Have a 3 layer architecture console application calling business layer and business layer calling Data Layer

Data Layer is using [Oracle.DataAccess 4.112.3.0 from Add Referance -> Assembly -> Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20Ddz.jpg)

Using that dll I was able to execute stored procedure at Oracle 11G server

**Error Recieved**

> The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter'
>   threw         an exception.

Please do let me know if I should have provided more information here.
Appreciate help from all techies here....

Comment: Did you install a Oracle client?

Comment: Yes I did installed Oracle client on SQL Server as I was facing problem only when i run using XP_CMDSHELL and not while executing the .exe from command prompt.